# display=:0 ccsm error

Tags: display, desktop-environments

I tried setting the compizconfig manage and display but the display=:0 ccsm gives error message ",Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIES-1... could not open display....AttributrError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ' get,-default-screen'
 The desktop is still blank purplish mauve color and pops up "system program problem detected do you want to report the problem. Cancel report problem" whichever button clicked on nothing happens.

Please I need help to bring up application/ programs on the desktop.

Comment: Are you typing `display=:0` or `DISPLAY=:0`? letter case is significant in *nix

Comment: I typed DISPLAY=:0